# Undefined index errors accessing $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms

I keep trying to fix this but it's giving me the same errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: items in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: body in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop.php on line 24

Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="items" value="fed" /> Fed<br />
    <input type="radio" name="items" value="body" /> Body<Br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
</form> 

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $items = $_POST['items'];
     if($items=="fed") {
         echo "You choose feds";    
         die();
     }
     else
         echo "<Form action='' method='POST'>
         <select name='body'>
         <option value='head'>Head</option>
         </select>
         <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' /><br />
         </form>";

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("feds",$connect)or die(mysql_error());
    
    $merchandise = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM merchandise WHERE body_part='$body' ")or     die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($merchandise)) {
        echo $row['item'];  
        echo "<bR>";
    }
}


} 
?>
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't really contain a *question* - so it will be difficult to answer (and it might be closed, too).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, a multi-step form?

Answer (score 3):

The error messages say that you're accessing an item of an array that doesn't exist!

But in general you should check the existence of these variables (even if you're sure that the form was sent):

```
$items = isset($_POST['items']) ? $_POST['items'] : outputError('...');
```

**And please fix your SQL injection security hole!!**

```
$body = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['body'] );
```

Please consider upgrading to **MySQLi** or **PDO**, too! There are many good resources on these topics out there.

Comment: @Tadeck I've just tested this code: `$arr = array('a' => ''); echo isset($arr['a']);` and it returns **true**. My PHP version: 5.4.12. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake (I was probably thinking about empty()).

Answer (score 2):

**These are not errors**, they are **notices**. But they should be fixed in the production environment, as this gives you a hint that your code may not be working correctly in some cases.

### Solution

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you can use the following code:

```
$items = array_key_exists('items', $_POST) ? $_POST['items'] : '';
```

and you are sure your `$items` variable contains something (at least empty string). Of course depending on your code architecture, you can replace empty string with `false` or `null`, but it is up to you.

### Tip about using `isset()` or `empty()`

Do not use them for checking if the specific element exists in array - use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). What is the difference?

Let's assume `$my_array` looks like that:

```
$my_array = array(
    'a' => 'abc',
    'b' => 0,
    'c' => '',
    'd' => null,
);
```

then:

- `empty()` on `$my_array['b']`, `$my_array['c']` and `$my_array['d']` will return `true`, as all these values are considered empty, and on `$my_array['e']` will also return `true`, as non-existent value/variable is also considered empty,
- `isset()` on all elements will return `true` with exception of `$my_array['d']`, because `isset()` treats variables equal to `null` as not set. `isset($my_array['e'])` will also return `false (because variable is not set),
- `array_key_exists()` will return `true` for every key that actually **exists** within array, and will return `false` if it does not,

So, as mentioned above, the better option for checking whether some element is defined in array is to use `array_key_exists()`, as it does not skip "empty" or `null` values.

### Appendix

There are links to the documentation:

- [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) - determines if a variable is set and is not `NULL`,
- [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) - determines whether a variable is empty (empty string, `0` as integer, `0.0` as float, `'0'` - zero as string, `null`, `false` or empty array `array()`),
- [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) - actually checks if the given key or index exists in the array,

Answer (score 0):

Undefined index means that you are trying to access an array key that does not exist. Your form probably is not posting like you are expecting. A simple:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

will show you what is posting.

Comment: That should be `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Thanks, I blame it all on the keyboard! =)

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand the logic as to what you are trying to do. Can you explain a bit more? Also your first `if` condition is closed incorrectly. Your structure is as follows:

```
if(user submits) //true
{
if(){ do something}
else{ do something}

if(user submits) //true
{
//you call body variable, which is not defined the first time user submits the page, thus the error
}

}//original if ends
```

So, check the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a hidden input for each form, instead af trying to listen to a submit button..
not all versions of php register the submit button as a value.
Also you wrote the "if(isset($_POST['submit']))" twice, which will make php return both if-statements true.. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code that echoes your form out to this:-

```
echo "<Form action='' method='POST'>
     <select name='body' id='body'>
     <option value='head'>Head</option>
     </select>
     <input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='submit' /><br />
     </form>";
```

Notice I have added id's to the form elements, it is best to use both id and name attributes set to the same value for forms.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just use method as "POST" instead of "post" .hope so it would solve your problem just like mine.

Happy coding