# cant see the result of an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

im trying to store an ajax respone to the Post php variable and then echo it on the same page, but sadly, it returns "Notice: Undefined index"

I think its something with the success part of the ajax.Could you help me correct it?

Thanks in advance:)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="ido" value="Click" /></td>
    </form>
    <script>

var x=document.getElementById("log");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="GPS szolgáltatás nem müködik ezen a böngészőn, kérlek értesítsd a rendszergazdát!";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
     $.ajax({
         url: "test.php", 
         type: 'POST', //I want a type as POST
         data: {'name' : latitude },
         success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
      });
    }
</script>

<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["ido"])){
    echo "<script>getLocation();</script>";
    $name=$_POST["name"];
print_r($_POST);
    }
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get the `alert`?

Comment: Indeed, I see no `name` sent to post. Undefined index means the array could not find the value you seek.

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300068/undefined-index-errors-accessing-post

Comment: `ido` is never set in the post... that's why you get the undefined index notice

Comment: how to send name to the post?

Comment: Where is Element with Id `log` . That is why you are getting error and You didn't declared `DocType` in firstline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your DOCTYPE declaration is wrong.
`getCurrentPosition` is a [HTML5 feature](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp).

Besides that `getCurrentPosition` needs a callback.
Also you don't need any php here before sending the ajax request.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="log"></div>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="ido" value="Click" /></td>
    </form>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();         

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ajaxCall);         
            }else{
                $('#log').html("GPS szolgáltatás nem müködik ezen a böngészőn, kérlek értesítsd a rendszergazdát!");
            }

        });

        function ajaxCall(position){
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php", 
                type: 'POST', //I want a type as POST
                data: {'latitude' : latitude, 'longitude' : longitude },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#log').html(response);
                }
            });
        }       
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your test.php should look like this:

```
<?php
    echo 'Latitude: '.$_POST['latitude'].'<br>';
    echo 'Latitude: '.$_POST['longitude'];
?>
```

Comment: Tried it, a kept my php code below of your updated code, now somehow if i press the button the php code doesnt run somehow.I dont understand :/

Comment: You don't need the php code below. The method submit registers the button click event. Try it without the php code. It also depends what's in the test.php. I've updated my answer with a sample code for test.php

Comment: Its almost working now, thanks for you help so far!!! Only question i want to ask, that how can i pair the " $('form').submit(function(e)" with another form? with id? or name?

Comment: You can replace form with whatever selector you want. E.g. if your form has an id of "geolocationForm" you can select it with $('#geolocationForm')